# Why does llama return None when response_mode is no_text?

Tags: python, langchain, llama-index

When I query using a LlaMA index, it returns a JSON object that has the response for the query and the source nodes (with the score) it used to generate an answer. But it not work.

```
engine = RetrieverQueryEngine.from_args(retriever, service_context,
                                                response_mode=ResponseMode.NO_TEXT)
res = engine.query('about price comment')
```

Comment: Can you provide more information about what llama-index version you are using?

Comment: version is 0.6.20, i saw nodes was print ,but not return

Comment: thx for your reply. I find the nodes are in the response object. 

response = index.as_query_engine(response_mode="no_text").query("query")
print(response.source_nodes)